# gvimrc partly not taken into account (Windows 7)

Tags: vim

I have just installed version 7.4 of GVim for Windows.
I have also created a gvimrc file with the following content:

```
set tabstop=2         " Set the tabstop to 2 spaces
set shiftwidth=2      " Shiftwidth should match tabstop
set expandtab         " Convert tabs to <tabstop> number of spaces
set smartindent       " Let vim help you with your code indention
highlight Comment guifg=#409040
highlight SpecialComment guifg=#409040
highlight String  guifg=Blue
highlight ColorColumn guibg=LightGray
set colorcolumn=81
set tw=0
```

Some lines are taken into account. 
For example: `set tabstop=2`

Other lines are NOT taken into account. 
For example: , `highlight Comment guifg=#409040`

If I run gvimrc file later with `:so $MYGVIMRC`, then all lines are taken into account.

So, what's wrong with these faulty lines?
Are they overwritten by something else?

Note: This gvimrc file works fine on Ubuntu and Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That *should* work, even though it's cleaner to create your own colorscheme instead of just selectively overriding some definitions. I suspect that something executes *after* your `.gvimrc` (maybe triggered by an event such as `GUIEnter`), and that (re-)sets the color definitions. The output of `:scriptnames` might help.

If you cannot find the root cause, and don't want to write your own `colors/myscheme.vim` file, try

```
:autocmd GUIEnter,ColorScheme * highlight Comment guifg=#409040
...
```

Comment: According to `:scriptnames`, gvimrc is the last called source.

Adding `:autocommand .....` as suggested fixes the issue.

Comment: Can it help fixing the root cause?

Comment: Great that you now have at least a workaround. To find the root cause, you need to investigate all commands listed by `:autocmd VimEnter,GUIEnter,ColorScheme`; one of those (hopefully) resets your highlight definitions.

Comment: I haven't found anything special resetting the highlight definitions. This answer is not entirely satisfactory because it is only a work-around, but I accept it as an answer. If anyone has more ideas on the root cause of the issue, please let me know. I am always interested in fixing things properly !

Answer (score 0):

See `:help initialization` to get a view of the full init process, it could help you fix your issue.

What could happen is that you set your colorscheme in your .vimrc, that is called before gvimrc. Sourcing of vimrc is step 3, as sourcing of gvimrc is in step 8 of init.

If this is the case, you can't redefine a color group that has already been defined. If you want to redefine something, on the fly, you have to first disable by using for example :

```
highlight Comment NONE            "remove the Comment highlight group
highlight Comment guifg=#409040   "redefine the Comment hightlight group
```

Comment: From where do you have the part about "not redefining a color group"? Also, it works when he explicitly sources his .gvimrc!

Comment: It seems it might be a misunderstanding from my part, but I have already observed that if I redefined an existing group without resetting it, it was not successful. Might be a bug, not a documented feature...

Comment: In my case, resetting the color before redefining it does not help.

Comment: did you check `:help initialization`? because it might be you are modifying the wrong file, like the system gvimrc that is overiddent by your home gvimrc, or something like that.

Comment: Yes, I have checked. It says that only the first gvimrc found is taken into account. As some lines of my file are executed, it means it takes my gvimrc file, not another one